# Check for duplicates before insert - Error messages

Tags: php, mysql

I want to add a 3rd error message to my insert query. 
At the moment I have 'Code valid' and 'Code invalid' and I can't figure out what do I have to do to add a 3rd Error message that will show on duplicate codes ?

Anyways, this is my code.

```
    <?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
   if (strlen($_POST['coda']) == 12 && substr($_POST['coda'],0,1) == '0'){
      $code = $_POST['coda'];
      $remote_addr = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
         $secret = $_POST['secret'];
      $select_query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE code = '$code' OR ip = '$remote_addr'");
      if(mysql_num_rows($select_query) == 0){
         mysql_query("INSERT INTO table(code,secret,ip,date,used,status) VALUES('$code','$secret','$remote_addr',CURDATE(),'n','pending')");

      }
      Print "<font color='green'>VALID CODE</font>"; 
} else { 

Print "<font color='red'>INVALID CODE</font>"; 
}

}?>
```

This is checking the validity

```
if (strlen($_POST['coda']) == 12 && substr($_POST['coda'],0,1) == '0')
```

Edit:

Figured it out.

Comment: Please post your solution as answer if you have figured it out.

Comment: @deceze I tried, but i can't. I do have to wait for 8 hours, as i don't have 100 Rep yet. I will post it as soon as i can.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure to understand your problem, but here is what I'm thinking :

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
   if (strlen($_POST['coda']) == 12 && substr($_POST['coda'],0,1) == '0'){
      $code = $_POST['coda'];
      $remote_addr = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
      $secret = $_POST['secret'];
      if(mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE code = '$code'")) > 0) {
         Print "<font color='red'>DUPLICATE CODE</font>";
      } else {
         $select_query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE code = '$code' OR ip = '$remote_addr'");
         if(mysql_num_rows($select_query) == 0){
            mysql_query("INSERT INTO table(code,secret,ip,date,used,status) VALUES('$code','$secret','$remote_addr',CURDATE(),'n','pending')");
            Print "<font color='green'>VALID CODE</font>"; 
         }
      }
   } else { 
      Print "<font color='red'>INVALID CODE</font>"; 
   }
}
?>
```

Comment: I have edited my first post, this should hopefully make it more clear.

Comment: Well you want to check if the code is already used in your database right?